# Spring Framework form validation, Hibernate beans and bean populating

Tags: java, spring, forms, validation

How can I make beans that contain Hibernate annonations and at the same time it would contain form validation annonations? And when I catch HTTP request I would like automatically populate this bean with form data. Is there any way to do this with Spring Framework tools? And are there any tools to print bean as html to jsp page?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make beans that contain
>   Hibernate annonations and at the same
>   time it would contain form validation
>   annonations?

You mean hibernate annotations like `@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` and bean validation annotations like `@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`? If so, you should first consider use only `javax.*` annotations, because (among many more reasons) your code can be portable in any provider.

> And when I catch HTTP request I would
>   like automatically populate this bean
>   with form data. Is there any way to do
>   this with Spring Framework tools?

If you're talking about Spring MVC, then it should be done automatically, you just have to create your `@Controller` methods and insert the appropriate parameters. You should take a look at the documentation at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html .

If you're working with pure servlets, you should consider using http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/ .

> And are there any tools to print bean
>   as html to jsp page?

Didn't catch that either. If you mean create a insert/edit form based on the bean's attributes, I don't know any tool or tag or thing that does the trick. But there are tools to generate html code based on a class.